# replacing html tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently reformatting some HTML pages with BeautifulSoup, and I ran into bit of a problem.

My problem is that the original HTML has things like this:

```
<li><p>stff</p></li>
```

and

```
<li><div><p>Stuff</p></div></li>
```

as well as

```
<li><div><p><strong>stff</strong></p></div><li>
```

With BeautifulSoup I hope to eliminate the div and the p tags, if they exists, but keep the strong tag.

I'm looking through the beautiful soup documentation and couldn't find any.
Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to do can be done using `replaceWith`. You have to duplicate the element you want to use as the replacement, and then feed that as the argument to `replaceWith`. The [documentation for `replaceWith`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another) is pretty clear on how to do this.

Comment: FWIW, http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with is the bs4 documentation

Answer (score 11):

This question probably refered to an older version of BeautifulSoup because with bs4 you can simply use the *[unwrap](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap)* function:

```
s = BeautifulSoup('<li><div><p><strong>stff</strong></p></div><li>')
s.div.unwrap()
>> <div></div>
s.p.unwrap()
>> <p></p>
s
>> <html><body><li><strong>stff</strong></li><li></li></body></html>
```

Answer (score 7):

I saw many answers for this simple question, i also came here to see something useful but unfortunately i didn't get what i was looking for then after few tries I found a simple solution for this answer and here it is

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData, "html.parser")

h2_headers = soup.find_all("h2")

for header in h2_headers:
    header.name = "h1" # replaces h2 tag with h1
```

All h2 tags converted to h1. You can convert any tag by just changing the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to strip tags:

```
import re

def strip_tags(string):
    return re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', string)

strip_tags("<li><div><p><strong>stff</strong></p></div><li>")
'stff'
```

Comment: yeah but i actually want the <strong> there. Also after looking through a couple random page, there's only div and p to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution get your whole node means `div`:

1. Convert to string
2. Replace `<tag>` with required tag/string.
3. Replace corresponding tag with empty string.
4. Convert the converted string to parsable string by passing to beautifulsoup

   What I have done for `mint`

   Example:

   ```
   <div class="col-md-12 option" itemprop="text">
   <span class="label label-info">A</span>

   **-2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1**
   ```

   ```
   sup = opt.sup 
       if sup: //opt has sup tag then

            //opts converted to string. 
            opt = str(opts).replace("<sup>","^").replace("</sup>","") //replacing

            //again converted from string to beautiful string.
            s = BeautifulSoup(opt, 'lxml')

            //resign to required variable after manipulation
            opts = s.find("div", class_="col-md-12 option")
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   -2^31 to 2^31-1
   without manipulation it will like this (-231 to 231-1)
   ```