# BeautifulSoup strip extra spaces

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a `soup.find_all('h2',{'class':'myclass'}` and the response has spaces after the opening tags and before closing tags, like so:

```
<h2 class="myclass"> This is a Headline </h2>
```

I want to get rid of the spaces, but keep the text and the open/close tags. What I have managed is to strip the spaces, but it doesn't seem like the element doesn't return properly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
html_code = '''
<html>
<body>
<h2 class="myclass"> This is a Headline </h2>
<h2 class="myclass"> Another H2 element </h2>
</body>
</html>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code,'lxml')
soup.prettify()
headings = soup.find_all('h2', {'class':'myclass'})
if headings:
    for heading in headings:
        del heading['class']
        heading_stripped = heading.text.strip()
        heading = '<h2>' + heading_stripped + '</h2>'
        print(heading)
print(soup)
```

If I `print(heading)` it returns correctly but if I `print(soup)` spaces are back.
Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Can you print 'heading_stripped'? I think you think modify 'heading' will change 'soup'?

Comment: As @Wonka mentioned. You actually don't  modify `soup`. Heading is just a variable only visible in context of for loop.

Comment: And to answer your actual question: Please take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907810/replacing-html-tags-with-beautifulsoup/20462375)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replacing html tags with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907810/replacing-html-tags-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the string of the tag like this:

```
heading.string=heading_stripped
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
html_code = '''
<html>
<body>
<h2 class="myclass"> This is a Headline </h2>
<h2 class="myclass"> Another H2 element </h2>
</body>
</html>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code,'lxml')
soup.prettify()
headings = soup.find_all('h2', {'class':'myclass'})
if headings:
    for heading in headings:
        del heading['class']        
        heading_stripped = heading.text.strip()
        heading.string=heading_stripped

print(soup)
```

#### Output

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>This is a Headline</h2>
<h2>Another H2 element</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign value to heading, you are not changing actual soup, just a heading variable. You can't modify soup directly, try using approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024877/change-the-text-of-the-inner-tag-using-beautifulsoup-python):

```py
heading.string.replace_with(heading.text.strip())
```